# Allow jasper server users to create a domain

Tags: jasperserver

I would like that some users could create domains on my JasperReports Server (users with role X),

I found a documentation were everything is explaind ([doc](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-allow-creation-domains-and-datasources-non-admin-users)), it worked in a demo enterprise version of JasperReports

but when I tried the same process on the production JasperReports (LDAP configured), I got this error :

***Error creating bean with name 'remoteServiceConfiguration' -> Error creating bean with name 'authenticationAuthoirizationFilterChainProxy'  ->
 Cannot resolve reference to bean 'filterInvocationInterceptor' while setting constructor argument with key [6] ->
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [L4_IT_DEVS] (my role)***

Screen : 
[image]

Has someone already had this kind of error when configuring domain creation for users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before and solved by using roles with the prefix "ROLE_" in their names, like "ROLE_L4_IT_DEVS" for example.

Hope that could help !